# AM/PM not working using between in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table called `task`:

```
id     t_started_on              t_due_on
------------------------------------------------    
 1    2018-01-12 10:45 AM    2018-01-12 07:45 PM
 2    2018-01-18 09:15 AM    2018-01-19 07:00 PM
 3    2018-01-16 02:30 AM    2018-01-22 10:30 AM
```

I want to select records where today's date is between the two date fields with AM or PM. Without AM/PM I know how to do it, but my AM/PM requirement is there:

Apart from the date comparison, also the time part should on its own fall between the time part of the start date and the time part of the due date.

How can I do this?

If current time stamp is '2018-01-19 03:56 PM' than with above data in the dabase, the results should have one row only (2<sup>nd</sup> row), but I am getting two rows in the results (also the 3<sup>rd</sup> row).

Here is my SQL Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `task` 
WHERE  '2018-01-19 03:56 PM' between t_started_on and t_due_on
```

The 3<sup>rd</sup> row should not be included because the time part of the due date is earlier than the time part of the current time.

Comment: You need to use a 24 hour time in the string literal.

Comment: Well I am getting the output right. Someting wrong with condition 't_status !=3'. check it

Comment: @ Sobmac, Sorry bro, i forgot to give  t_status (column name)

Comment: I have severely edited your question to explain the time requirement. Please check that it reflects what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better store your dates as `DATETIME`. As you have these values, it already shows your database fields are not of the `date` type, as inserting such strings into `date` fields would not produce an error.

If this is not possible to change, then you can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `task` 
WHERE t_status !=3 
AND   STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-19 03:56 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') BETWEEN
        STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AND 
        STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
```

But that is really an inferior solution.

Still, your expectation to only get one row seems strange. Certainly the third row meets the requirement, since the start/due dates are before/after the date you are checking, irrespective of the time parts.

#### Addendum

In comments you are saying you want to apply a different logic. I'm *guessing* you want to compare separately the date and time components, and both to comply to the `between` condition. This really should be explained in the question, as currently it is not specified.

In that case, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to extract only the time part, and repeat the condition with that:

```
SELECT *,
       STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),
       STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),
       STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-19 03:56 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
FROM `task` 
WHERE t_status !=3 
AND   STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-19 03:56 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') BETWEEN
        STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AND 
        STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
AND   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-19 03:56 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'), '%h:%i') BETWEEN
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'), '%h:%i') AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'), '%h:%i')
```

This query will exclude the 3<sup>rd</sup> row from the result.

Comment: No,Not correct answer, it is coming two row only bro

Comment: The third row also fulfills the condition. The 3rd row's start date is 16 January, and its end date is 22 January. Obviously 19 January is in between those two, irrespective of the time. I must be misunderstanding your question if you expected something else. NB: I am not your bro

Comment: Check AM/PM Condition is not matching,my date 3rd row having AM but we are checking PM (2018-01-19 03:56 PM), that means 3rd row should not come

Comment: I know that there is AM/PM, but when a time is on a *different* date, it does not matter whether it is AM or PM. 22 January 2018 is *always* later than 19 January 2018, whether you are looking at an AM or PM time does not change that.

Comment: I want to get only AM records means,between two dates that PM records should not come Mr. trincot

Comment: I am now *guessing* you want to compare the time part separately, on top of the date comparison. See the "addendum" I have added to my answer. Please edit your question to clarify this requirement.