# How to make single array in between dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table called `task`

```
id          t_title              t_started_on               t_due_on
 1           Test 1           2018-01-18 01:00 PM            2018-01-20 01:00 PM
 2           Test 2           2018-01-25 01:00 PM            2018-01-27 01:00 PM
```

from here i have to select dates like first row start date is 2018-01-18 01:00 PM (`t_started_on`) and end date is 2018-01-20 01:00 PM(`t_due_on`).total is 3 days

1. 2018-01-18
2. 2018-01-19
3. 2018-01-20

same as second row also 3 days

1. 2018-01-25
2. 2018-01-26
3. 2018-01-27

Expected Result

```
    Array
(
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-18
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-19
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-20
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-25
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-26
    [allocatedDate] => 2018-01-27
)
```

How to write a select query in above case?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339446/5459839), you should *not* store your dates as strings, but in `date` datatype: that will make your data less error prone and your queries simpler. Now you'll have to convert those strings to dates each time you need to do date/time calculations with them.

To generate the dates inside periods, you need a helper table, which can be useful also for many other purposes: a table with one column that has natural numbers starting from 0 up to some large *n*. You could create it like this:

```
create table nums (i int);
insert into nums values (0), (1), (2), (3);
insert into nums select i+4 from nums;
insert into nums select i+8 from nums;
insert into nums select i+16 from nums;
insert into nums select i+32 from nums;
insert into nums select i+64 from nums;
insert into nums select i+128 from nums;
insert into nums select i+256 from nums;
```

You can see how you double the number of records by adding a similar insert statement, but this will already generate 512 records, which would be more than enough for your purposes: it should have the highest number of days that a period can have in your tasks table.

Then you can use this query to get the desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_add(d_started_on, interval i day)
FROM   (
        SELECT date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) as d_started_on,
               datediff(
                   date(STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d')),
                   date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d'))
               ) as days
        FROM   tasks
       ) as base
INNER JOIN nums ON i <= days
ORDER BY 1
```

See also [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c1346/9)

Comment: Suppose tasks table having 2000 records means helper table nums(512 records enough or we have to increase ?)

Comment: Is enough. You need only enough values to cover for the record that has the largest difference between start and due dates. So if there is a record that has a due date that is 1000 days later than the start date, then you need to add more records to the `nums` table.

Comment: Thanks,Now i got my exact answer

Comment: Mr trincot, I tried to add where condition in above query but throwing error like `Unknown column 't_assign_to' in 'where clause' `,but task table i have t_assign_to column

Comment: **SELECT DISTINCT date_add(date(d_started_on), interval i day) as allocation_date FROM ( SELECT date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) as d_started_on, datediff( date(STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d')), date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) ) as days FROM task ) as base INNER JOIN nums ON i <= days WHERE `t_assign_to` ='G2E0357' ORDER BY 1**

Comment: I tried like above sql query,it is correct or not ?